# Filter a PowerApps Data source for BrowseGallery based on Sharepoint column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

I am designing an asset management PowerApp which is based on a SharePoint Online list. It takes fields such as type of item (eg. laptop, server or printer etc.) and allows the user to currently filter based on a scanned barcode. 
However I have now created a menu screen, which the user chooses whether they would like to search for a laptop or a server. This navigates them to a different screen depending on what they choose. I would like to filter the data source based on a value within the `AssetType` field. This is a multiple choice field that is either Laptops, Servers or Printers

The current formula for the BrowseGallery is  `SortByColumns(Filter(EquipmentInventory, StartsWith(Barcode, BarcodeScanner1.Value)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`

I have tried `SortByColumns(Filter(EquipmentInventory.ItemType == "Laptop", StartsWith(Barcode, BarcodeScanner1.Value)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`

and also

`SortByColumns(Search([@AssetType], BrowseScreen_SearchInput.Text in AssetType && AssetType.Value = "Laptops", "AssetType", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`

to try filter the data source to only show Laptops but I am getting an error of invalid arguments.

Once I can get this working, the expected result would be to have a filter on each screen, displaying Laptops on the laptops screen etc.

I would like each screen to display a BrowseGallery of its assets and then allow the user to still search based on barcode.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the Filter formula try something like: `Filter(EquipmentInventory, ItemType = 'Name of screen 1 item type selector'.Selected.ItemType.Value)`

The error you are seeing is because the formula is trying to compare two items with different types. To test this, I usually like to add a label to my screen and test each part of the comparison to make sure the values are what I expect. For example, set the label text to be ItemType and the 'Name of screen 1 item type selector'.Selected.ItemType.Value part and make sure they show the same value.

Once you get the filter working, the SortByColumns part should work too!

Comment: Thanks Emily for your help! Could you clarify what the ItemType selector should be in this case? I have tried `Filter(EquipmentInventory, AssetType = "Laptops".Selected.AssetType.Value)`

Comment: What I mean by the item type selector is whatever way you are "passing" the user input from Screen1 to Screen2. You could have a gallery on Screen1 that shows the item types and they pick one by clicking the arrow icon and then you would use Gallery1.Selected.ItemType.Value in your filter formula. Or you could have radio buttons and a Select button that launches Screen2 and then you'd use Radio1.Selected.Value. Or you could have three buttons (one per item type) and set a new variable to 'Laptops', 'Printers', or 'Servers' and then use that variable in your formula. It's really up to you!